# How to import excel file when each column divides into sub columns in SAS

Tags: excel, import, sas, xls, tabular

I have a excel file that each column is divided into sub columns . I tried to import it in following way

```
PROC IMPORT DATAFILE="path\IRCC_M_PRadmiss_0002_E (1).xls"
     OUT=immigrants
     DBMS=XLS REPLACE;
     getnames=yes;
    
RUN;
```

[image: Image of the dataset after import]
But in this way i am getting column names as observations. I want to import it in more structured way so that columns can be accessed by their names.
Link to the excel file : https://files.fm/u/bapkwx7mk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Excel file appears to contain a pivot table based on some other categorical data source.  If you have access to that data source, import it instead.

Suppose the Excel file is a download from some government website and the original data is unavailable.

As you found out a single simple IMPORT will make all the columns character due to mixed types in the header cells and the values in the column headers pollute the flat import.

A pivot table has three parts

- The column headers (A crossing of class variables)

  - The table in your file crosses three variables
    **Year**, **Quarter**, and **Month**
- The row headers (A crossing of class variables)

  - The table in your file crosses one variable
    **Country**
- The data portion (the cells where the dimensions intersect)

  - Your table contains count totals

`Proc IMPORT` can read ranges of cells from an Excel file and this gives rise to the following strategy for **unpivoting the pivot table**:

- IMPORT the column header part,
- IMPORT the row header and data portion together.  This can be done because the row header is one dimensional.
- TRANSPOSE the column header part and the row header + data part and merge into a final categorical form.

  - The merging will associate a categorical (or class) values (country, year, quarter, and month) to each data cell.

IMPORTING with `GETNAMES=NO` will produce a *raw* starting point where each column from Excel will be named **`F<nn>`**.  When the raw data is transposed you will have a new column named `_NAME_` whose values will be **`"F<nn>"`**.  The column names have just become data.

Looking across the cells in the data portion, each row has 98 columns that would become 98 rows when transposed. However, the *totals* columns can be discarded, and you will be left with 72 rows (in transpose) corresponding to 6 years * 12 months/year.

The original report can be reproduced using `Proc TABULATE` once you have transformed the IMPORTs into categorical time.

Example:

The values of the `_NAME_` variable are mapped to a corresponding month using a custom informat built from the column header transpose.

```
* read column headers;

PROC IMPORT DATAFILE="C:\Users\Richard\Downloads\IRCC_M_PRadmiss_0002_E (1).xls"
  REPLACE OUT=headers_raw
  ;
  RANGE="A3:CT5";
  GETNAMES=NO;
RUN;

* read row header and data part (the counts);

PROC IMPORT DATAFILE="C:\Users\Richard\Downloads\IRCC_M_PRadmiss_0002_E (1).xls"
  REPLACE OUT=data_raw
  ;
  RANGE="A6:CT204";
  GETNAMES=NO;
RUN;

proc transpose data=headers_raw 
  out=headers_tall(
    drop=_label_
    where=(col3 not contains 'Total' and col2 not contains 'Total')
  );
  var F2-F98;
run;

* construct special CNTLIN data set for custom informat named FIELD_TO_MONTH;

data headers_cntlin;
  length start $32 label 8;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    hlo = 'O';
    label = .;
    output;
    hlo = '';
  end;

  set headers_tall;
  retain year;
  if not missing (col1) then year = input(col1,4.);

  retain fmtname 'FIELD_TO_MONTH' type 'i';

  month = input (cats('01',col3,year), date9.);

  start = _name_;
  label = month;
  output;

  keep fmtname start label type hlo;
run;

* build the custom informat;

proc format cntlin=headers_cntlin;
run;

* F1 is the one-dimensional row header;
* F2-F98 are the data cells;
* after transpose the column names will be data in column _NAME_;

proc transpose data=data_raw
  out=data_tall(
    drop=_label_ 
    rename=(F1=Country col1=count)
    index=(_name_)
  );
  by F1 notsorted;
  var F2-F98;
run;

data immigration;
  set data_tall;
  label Country=' ';

  * map field name to month per column headers;

  month = input(_name_,FIELD_TO_MONTH.);
  if not missing(month);

  * variables for wider temporal aggregations in time hierarchy year/qtr/month;

  year = year(month);  
  qtr  = qtr(month);   format qtr NLSTRQTR2.1;

  format month monname3.;

  keep country year qtr month count;
run;

* reproduce the Excel pivot table in SAS;

ods html file='immigration.html' style=plateau;

proc tabulate data=immigration;
  class year qtr month / order=internal;
  class country;
  var count;

  table 
    country
    ,
    ( year=''
    * ( qtr=''
      * ( month='' 
          all
        )
        all
       )
       all
    )
    * count='' * sum=' ' * f=comma12.
    ;
run;

ods html close;
```

Headers raw (from range)

[image]

Data raw (from range)

[image]

Headers tall

[image]

Headers CNTLIN for custom informat FIELD_TO_MONTH

[image]

Data tall (72 rows per country for 6 years and 12 months / year)

[image]

Immigration after applying informat to field names (F2....) to compute variables for temporal hierarchy

[image]

Original table reproduced by `TABULATE`

[image]